# Laravel how to test when coming across redirections Expected status code 200 but received 302

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I am using Laravel 5.6, I have a simple test which checks a user is able to be registered, as follows;

```
public function it_registers_successfully()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([ 'password' => bcrypt('foobar') ]);

    $payload = [ 'name' => $user->name, 'email' => $user->email, 'password' => 'foobar' ];

    $response = $this->post('/api/register', $payload);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

When i run the test i am receiving the following;

```
Expected status code 200 but received 302.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I am new to testing, but i think the problem is that the register function checks to see if the user should be logged in on a successful register and then does it, hence the redirection.

I know this is defeating the purpose and going backwards to how its meant to be done, but i would like some advice on how to deal with the redirection and see the 200 status.

The function is as follows;

```
public $loginAfterSignUp = true;

public function register(RegisterAuthRequest $request)
{
    // Build new user collection
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

    // Save user
    $user->save();

    // Check if user should be automatically logged in
    if ($this->loginAfterSignUp) {
        return $this->login($request);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $user
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: You need to write separate tests for the cases of `loginAfterSignup` being either true or false.

Comment: How would i set the property in the test?